# OpenCL C program gives bizzare output

Tags: c, linux, parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu

I have written a simple OpenCL C code. Its kernel code is:

```
__kernel void hello(__global int * A,__global int * B)
{
    int x=get_global_id(0);
    B[x]=x;
    A[x]+=1;
}
```

Below is a part of host code:

```
int main()
{
    cl_platform_id* platforms=NULL;
    cl_device_id* devices=NULL;
    cl_uint ret,platformCount,deviceCount;
    cl_context context = NULL;
    cl_command_queue command_queue=NULL;
    char* name;
    int i,j,l;
    size_t size;
    cl_mem memobj = NULL;
    cl_mem memobj1 = NULL;
    cl_program program = NULL;
    cl_kernel kernel = NULL;
    int array_size=10;
    int *A=(int*)malloc(array_size*sizeof(int));
    int *B=(int*)malloc(array_size*sizeof(int));
    printf("\nhey");
    for(i=0;i<array_size;i++)
        A[i]=0;
    ret=clGetPlatformIDs(0,NULL,&platformCount);
    printf("\n-----------------Found %d platforms-----------\n",platformCount);
    platforms=(cl_platform_id*)malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id)*platformCount);
    ret=clGetPlatformIDs(platformCount,platforms,NULL);
    if(ret==CL_SUCCESS)
        printf("\nPlatform ids obtained successfully!");
    for(i=platformCount-1;i>=0;i--)
    {   
        char * platformname;
        printf("\n-------------In platform %d-----------------",i);
        ret=clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_NAME ,0,NULL,&size);
        platformname=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
        ret=clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_NAME ,size,platformname,NULL);
        if(ret==CL_SUCCESS)
            printf("\nPlatform info obtained successfully!");

        printf("\n----------------For %s-----------------------",platformname);

        ret=clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i],CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT,NULL,NULL,&deviceCount);
        devices=(cl_device_id*)malloc(sizeof(cl_device_id)*deviceCount);
        ret=clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i],CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT,deviceCount,devices,NULL);
        if(ret==CL_SUCCESS)
            printf("\nFound %d devices!",deviceCount);

        for(j=0;j<deviceCount;j++)
        {
            char*devicename;
            printf("\n-------------Device %d.%d-----------------",i,j+1);
            ret=clGetDeviceInfo(devices[j], CL_DEVICE_NAME ,0,NULL,&size);
            devicename=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
            ret=clGetDeviceInfo(devices[j], CL_DEVICE_NAME ,size,devicename,NULL);
            if(ret==CL_SUCCESS)
                printf("\nDevice info obtained successfully!");
            printf("\nThe device name is %s && size=%d\n",devicename,size);

            printf("\nFound %d corresponding devices",deviceCount);
            context=clCreateContext(NULL,1,&devices[j], NULL, NULL, &ret);
            if(ret==CL_SUCCESS)
                printf("\nContext created successfully");

            command_queue=clCreateCommandQueue(context,devices[j], CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE,&ret);
            if(ret==CL_SUCCESS)
                printf("\nCommand queue created successfully");

            memobj=clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE ,array_size*sizeof(int),NULL,&ret);
            if(ret==CL_SUCCESS)
                printf("\nMemory object 1 created successfully");
            memobj1=clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE ,array_size*sizeof(int),NULL,&ret);
            if(ret==CL_SUCCESS)
                printf("\nMemory object 2 created successfully");
            ret=clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, memobj, CL_TRUE, 0, array_size*sizeof(int), A, 0, NULL, NULL);
            if(ret==CL_SUCCESS)
                printf("\nData written into buffer1  successfully");
            ret=clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, memobj1, CL_TRUE, 0, array_size*sizeof(int),B, 0, NULL, NULL);
            if(ret==CL_SUCCESS)
            printf("\nData written into buffer2 successfully");
             FILE *fp;
                char fileName[] = "./6.cl";
                char *source_str;
                size_t source_size;
                /* Load kernel code */
                fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
                if (!fp) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
                exit(1);
                }
                source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
                source_size = fread(source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
                printf("\nThe program is \n%s\n",source_str);
                fclose(fp);

            program=clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source_str,(const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);       
            if(ret==CL_SUCCESS)
            printf("\nProgram created successfully");

            ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &devices[j], NULL, NULL, NULL);        
            if(ret==CL_SUCCESS)
                printf("\nProgram built successfully");

            ret=clGetProgramBuildInfo(program,devices[j], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS ,0,NULL,&size);
            printf("\n Program buildinfo status=%d",ret);
            cl_build_status *status=(cl_build_status *)malloc(sizeof(cl_build_status )*size);
            clGetProgramBuildInfo(program,devices[j], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS ,size,status,NULL);
            printf("\nBuild status=%d\n",*status);

            printf("\nBuild log i=%d, j=%d",i,j);
            ret=clGetProgramBuildInfo(program,devices[j], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG ,0,NULL,&size);
            printf("\nclGetProgramBuildInfo ret1=%d",ret);
            char buildlog[2048];
            ret=clGetProgramBuildInfo(program,devices[j], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG ,sizeof(buildlog),buildlog,NULL);
            printf("\nclGetProgramBuildInfo ret2=%d",ret);
            printf("\n!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Program ended!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
            printf("\n\nBuildlog:   %s\n\n",buildlog);



            kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "hello", &ret);
            if(ret==CL_SUCCESS)
                printf("\nKernel created successfully");
            ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *) &memobj);
            printf("\nKernel argument 1=%d",ret);
            ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *) &memobj1);
            printf("\nKernel argument 2=%d",ret);
            cl_uint work_dim = 1;       
            size_t global_item_size=array_size;
            size_t local_item_size=32;
            cl_event event;
            ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, work_dim, NULL,&global_item_size, &local_item_size,0,NULL,&event);  
            if(ret==CL_SUCCESS)
                printf("\nKernel executed successfully");
            //ret=clEnqueueTask(command_queue,kernel,0,NULL,NULL);
            clWaitForEvents(1, &event);//make sure kernel has finished
            clFinish(command_queue);//make sure all enqueued tasks finished
            //get the profiling data and calculate the kernel execution time

            cl_ulong time_start, time_end;
            double total_time;
            clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
            clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);
            total_time = (cl_double)(time_end - time_start)/1000000.0;
            printf("OpenCl Execution time is: %10.5f[ms] \n",total_time);
            ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, memobj1, CL_TRUE, 0,array_size * sizeof(int), B, 0, NULL, NULL);
            ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, memobj, CL_TRUE, 0,array_size * sizeof(int), A, 0, NULL, NULL);
            int t;
            printf("\nThe result is:");
            for(t=0;t<array_size;t++)
                printf("\t%d",B[t]);
            printf("\nThe result A is:");
            for(t=0;t<array_size;t++)
                printf("\t%d",A[t]);

            //Read file here
            }
        }

    return 0;

}
```

I am facing a couple of issues:

1. The program outputs garbage values for array B and returns array A unmodified.
2. If instead of `ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, work_dim, NULL,&global_item_size, &local_item_size,1,NULL,&event);`
   I use `ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, work_dim, NULL,&global_item_size, &local_item_size,0,NULL,NULL);`, The program outputs correct result. I am running this code on 2 GPUs and a CPU. If I use latter form of clEnqueueNDRangeKernel i.e. without profiling, I get correct output in the GPUs while garbage values in case of the CPU.
3. The code lists fewer devices for a particular platform than those which are actually available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, work_dim, NULL,&global_item_size, &local_item_size,1,NULL,&event);
```

You are passing an empty (`NULL`) event wait-list, but claiming that it has 1 event in it. This will fail, and if you were checking the error codes from your OpenCL API calls (which you should *always* be doing), you will likely be getting `CL_INVALID_EVENT_WAIT_LIST` back, which would have pointed you towards the problem.

If you just want to retrieve the event back from a kernel (e.g. for profiling), but don't want to pass any event dependencies to it, then the correct form would be this:

```
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, work_dim, NULL,&global_item_size, &local_item_size,0,NULL,&event);
```

---

A second problem with the code that you have provided is that your work-group size does not exactly divide the global size:

```
size_t global_item_size=array_size; // which is 10
size_t local_item_size=32;
```

This will cause `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` to return `CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`, and fail to enqueue any work.

---

> The code lists fewer devices for a particular platform than those which are actually available.

You are requesting all of the devices of type `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT`. If you really want *all* of the devices, then use `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL`. If you just want GPU devices, then ask for `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU`.

Comment: This works. And it gives correct output on both the GPUs but it gives garbage values when I run this code on CPU.

Comment: Are you checking the error codes returned by *every single OpenCL API call*? If you have, and they are all `CL_SUCCESS`, please update your question with the full host code and I can take another look.

Comment: Update: This code gives garbage values when run for the first time irrespective of the device used. Actually I am running two loops viz 1
 for(i=platformCount-1;i>=0;i--){  
  /*Get corresponding device ids in the array devices */
  for(j=0;j<deviceCount;j++){ 
      //Run the code 
  } 
 }

Comment: OK, check all of the error codes, and if they are all fine then update the question with a complete, minimal example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @ikk Updated answer with a second issue. After fixing that, your code works fine for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82807/discussion-between-ikk-and-jprice).

Comment: Would you be kind to look into a third issue which I just now noticed. @jprice

Comment: ^^ chameleon question:(